# Accessing json data by a list of strings?

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-2.7, dictionary

I have this json:

```
json = {
    "state": {
        "reported": {
            "figure": {"x":10, "y":12, "z":12},
            "gif": {"x":10,"y":12, "z":12}
        }
    }
}
```

and this list of strings:

```
lista = ["json['state']['reported']['figure']['x']",
         "json['state']['reported']['figure']['y']",
         "json['state']['reported']['gif']['z']"]
```

I would like to know if there is a way to get the result of the json using this list?

Comment: You may fetch out the dict keys in your list using regex and then recursively get the value from your json object. But ideally you should be changing the logic to form that strings in your list and instead create the list of keys, if possible

Comment: Here is an unsafe, yet effective, way to do it: `result = [eval(item) for item in lista]`.

Comment: Not that unsafe for hard-coded data

Comment: Please don't use `eval` for this (or for anything for that matter). There are modules like `jsonpath` designed for this purpose.

Comment: @zwer i don't understand why everyone is against eval. Sure `eval(input())` is begging for code inj, but what's wrong with this `x = eval('1')` ?

Comment: @t.m.adam -- because it's cleaner/better/faster to write `x = int('1')`.  ;-).  I think your point is that if the input is trusted, then there is no issue.  At some level, that's a reasonable point.  The problem is that what was written to handle trusted input today will often be borrowed or copy/pasted to handle untrusted input tomorrow.  When that happens, you're asking for a world of hurt so it's probably better to get it right the first time around (just in case).

Comment: @mgilson i see your point, and i agree `eval` is not good practice. Still if you blindly copy-paste chunks of code eval is the least of your worries..

Comment: @t.m.adam -- It's not necessarily just blindly copy/pasting.  Sometimes the function with `eval` gets buried in other function calls.  What started as a 1-off script becomes a library which gets included in other projects and ...

Comment: @mgilson i wouldn't use eval on production code either, i'm just saying it's not that 'evil' for small user made scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in another answer, you *can* use `eval` for this.  There are even tricks to make it a little more difficult for hackers to take control of your system.  This is by far the *easiest* route, however, there isn't a clear way to make this actually safe.  Any of those tricks that you play will only give you a false sense of security.  Therefore DO NOT use it if you do not trust the source of `lista` completely.  Bad things will happen.

The good news is that if you're willing to write (or copy/paste) a little more code, **we can use python's AST to do this safely**.  The trick will be to parse the string into an AST.  We'll then create a class that can walk the AST and take appropriate (and safe) actions when certain types of nodes are found.  In your example, there are 4 types of nodes that we need to deal with:

- `Str`: Represents a string literal.
- `Name`: Represents a name lookup.  e.g. `json`
- `Subscript`: Represents a `__getitem__` call.
- `Index`: The object that will get passed to `__getitem__`.  In general this could be a slice too -- but that isn't in the inputs that you've shown, so we'll not support it for now.

Other types of nodes that you might need (depending on the inputs) are `Num`, and `Slice`.  It should be straight forward to implement them once you've grokked the [ast reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#abstract-grammar) (which can be somewhat obscure if you haven't looked at it before).

Now writing our class starts to look pretty simple:

```
class Evaluator(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self, globals):
        self._globals = globals

    def visit_Str(self, n):
        return n.s

    def visit_Name(self, n):
        return self._globals[n.id]

    def visit_Subscript(self, n):
        item = self.visit(n.value)
        slce = self.visit(n.slice)
        return item[slce]

    def visit_Index(self, n):
        return self.visit(n.value)

    def visit_Expr(self, n):
        return self.visit(n.value)
```

In action, it looks like:

```
e = Evaluator({'json': json})
print([e.visit(ast.parse(s).body[0]) for s in lista])
```

Comment: can you tell how to use this sscript if i have for example:  json1=json.dumps(json)   ???????

Comment: @Adler: Your follow-on question makes no sense since you are trying to use `json` to represent both the `json` module _and_ the dictionary variable in your question. You could use `import json as json_module` to avoid that, which would allow you to write `json1 = json_module.dumps(json)`, `e = Evaluator({'json': json})`, then `print([e.visit(ast.parse(s).body[0]) for s in lista])`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use python's eval function. That being said, this is a really bad idea because eval is a dangerous function. Please check this link for more info on the eval function: https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

```
json = {
    "state": {
        "reported": {
            "figure": {"x": 10, "y": 12, "z": 12},
            "gif": {"x": 10, "y": 12, "z": 12}
        }}}

lista = [
    "json['state']['reported']['figure']['x']",
    "json['state']['reported']['figure']['y']",
    "json['state']['reported']['gif']['z']"
]

values = [eval(x) for x in lista]
```